# Как при инициализации сервлета, узнать базовый URL?

Tags: servlet, java

Доброго дня.
Необходимо при старте web-приложения, записать в статическую переменную Base Url, чтобы в течении работы программы, можно было из любого места выдрать базовый url.
У кого какие идеи?
P.S.  Постоянно при get или post запросах брать из request базовый url не катит.

Comment: Что вы имеете подразумеваете под базовым URL? Имя хоста или контекст servlet-контейнера, в который задеплоено приложение?

Comment: Имя хоста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя хоста можно получить следующим образом:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Но возвращаемое значение зависит от конфигурации системы.